# Ftp File polling in Load Balancer

Tags: spring-integration

I have created FTP polling using SPring Inetegration (FTP adaptors).Just like to know is there any known issues if i use in the loadbalancer. i.e we have our app deployed in  2 instance of server with LoadBalancer.

Just thinking if File is polled by one FTP Poller and processing and another FTP poller will again poll the same file and process?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose Spring Integration 3.0 has introduced [`FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound)

There is just need to use shared external Persistence `MetadataStore` - Redis or Gemfire.
Or implement your own, for example JDBC.

And contribute it to Spring Integration - https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT

Comment: Note that while the basic persistent accept once file list filters were introduced in 3.0, support for shared metadata (`ConcurrentMetadataStore`) and the framework implementations (Redis, Gemfire) were not added until 4.0. So, 4.0.x or above is required for clustered FTP adapters using this technique.